# Apache Spark union method giving inexplicable result

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I was playing with the Moby Word's list using Apache Spark, here is the [file](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/words.txt).
I first created an RDD using this textfile

```
    lines = sc.textFile("words.txt")
```

And then created two RDDs containing words which have "p" and "s" in them

```
    plines = lines.filter(lambda x: "p" in x)
    slines = lines.filter(lambda x: "s" in x)
```

and then created a union of these two

```
    union_list = slines.union(plines)
```

I then counted the number of words in each list with the "count" method and that came out as 64803, 22969 and 87772 for slines, plines and union_list respectively. *Also 64803+22969=87772, which means there are no words with both "p" and "s".* I created a new RDD containing words with "p" **and** "s" using

```
    pslines = lines.filter(lambda x: ("p" in x) and ("s" in x))
```

and counted the elements which gave 13616, and then created a new RDD containing words with "p" **or** "s"

```
    newlist = lines.filter(lambda x: ("p" in x) or ("s" in x))
```

and counted the elements which gave 74156, *which makes sense cause 64803+22969-13616=74156.* What did I do wrong with the union method? I am using Spark 1.6 on Windows 10 and Python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[union()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd-pysrc.html#RDD.union) method is not a set union operation. It just concatenats two RDD's, so the intersection will be counted twice. If you want the true set union, you need to run [distinct()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#distinct) on your resulting RDD:

`union_list = slines.union(plines).distinct()`